# Bluetooth Media Controls Not Working After Recent Updates

Tags: audio, drivers, bluetooth, windows-10-v1803

The following updates were recently installed together:

Feature update to Windows 10, version 1803

HP Development Company, L.P. - System - 7.0.1.1

HP - HIDClass - 2.1.3.1

Since the updates, the Bluetooth media controls on my headphones (Sony MDR-XB650BT) have stopped working. I used to get input from the Play/Pause and seek buttons. The headphones are now only able to connect and play sound. I uninstalled, reinstalled, and updated the Intel BT driver and reinstalled the headset in Settings, but it did not help. Also, the updates from HP are not available to be removed using restore points. What can be done to make the media controls work again?

Specs: HP Envy W2K71UA / Windows 10 x64 v. 1803 / Intel Wireless Bluetooth driver v. 20.20.0.5

Comment: I seem to have same issue with my headphones (Plantronics BackBeat PRO), was able to Play/Pause VLC before the update, but it has not been working since.